# Blue-Burst-Patch-Project keeps failing to build - visual studio 2022 c++14/17

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

Edit: I have tried to contact the repository owner and they were unhelpful in figuring out why it wouldn't build

I can't get [Blue-Burst-Patch-Project](https://github.com/Solybum/Blue-Burst-Patch-Project) to build in visual studio 2022

I've tried building it with the c++17 standard and the compiler says

```
1>C:\Users\Lenka\Desktop\Blue-Burst-Patch-Project-master\Blue Burst Patch Project\common.cpp(84,38): error C4996: 'std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,1114111,(std::codecvt_mode)0>': warning STL4017: std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the <codecvt> header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard doesn't provide equivalent non-deprecated functionality; consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from <Windows.h> instead. You can define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to suppress this warning.
1>D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\codecvt(35,1): message : see declaration of 'std::codecvt_utf8'
1>C:\Users\Lenka\Desktop\Blue-Burst-Patch-Project-master\Blue Burst Patch Project\common.cpp(84,17): error C4996: 'std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,1114111,(std::codecvt_mode)0>,wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t>,std::allocator<char>>': warning STL4017: std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the <codecvt> header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard doesn't provide equivalent non-deprecated functionality; consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from <Windows.h> instead. You can define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to suppress this warning.
1>D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xlocbuf(304,1): message : see declaration of 'std::wstring_convert'
1>C:\Users\Lenka\Desktop\Blue-Burst-Patch-Project-master\Blue Burst Patch Project\common.cpp(84,62): error C4996: 'std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,1114111,(std::codecvt_mode)0>,wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t>,std::allocator<char>>::from_bytes': warning STL4017: std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the <codecvt> header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard doesn't provide equivalent non-deprecated functionality; consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from <Windows.h> instead. You can define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to suppress this warning.
```

And then I tried building it in the c++ 14 standard and it says

```
1>C:\Users\Lenka\Desktop\Blue-Burst-Patch-Project-master\Blue Burst Patch Project\hooking.h(37,17): error C2429: language feature 'init-statements in if/switch' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'
1>C:\Users\Lenka\Desktop\Blue-Burst-Patch-Project-master\Blue Burst Patch Project\hooking.h(35,29): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'void Hooking::Hook::CallHookCallbacks(void)'
```

And at the bottom of the compiler output it always just says

```
1>Done building project "Blue Burst Patch Project.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 6:05 PM and took 09.433 seconds ==========
```

Any one else able to get this thing to build?

Comment: [C++17: codecvt_utf8 is deprecated](https://codingtidbit.com/2020/02/09/c17-codecvt_utf8-is-deprecated/) - what the compiler tries to say you.

Comment: I got in contact with the owner of the repository and they were completely unhelpful. That's why I'm here lol.

Comment: As the error message says I added `#define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING` as the first line of `common.cpp` and it builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975182/blue-burst-patch-project-keeps-failing-to-build-visual-studio-2022-c14-17/77975341#comment137466274_77975182)

> As the error message says I added `#define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING` as the first line of `common.cpp` and it builds fine.

Resolved the issue.